# We usually have my mother (to) stay over Christmas

Tags: causative-have, experiential-have

> *We usually have my mother (**to**) stay over Christmas*

What differences in meaning or otherwise are due to the insertion
of **TO** ?

OED **HAVE** (vb) : https://oed.com/oed2/00103269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idiomatic usage:

**To have someone do something.**

To have my mother stay over Christmas.

To have my son cut the grass.

To have my husband fix the car.

To have someone **to** dinner. [to invite them for dinner or lunch]
To have someone **to** lunch.

That is not the same idiom.

**With the *to* preposition:**

**One British consultant suggested**
**a semantic difference**: She had her to stay implies an invitation, whereas She
had her stay suggests an unwilling imposition.  1990 Aug. 26 Sunday Times Magazine
9/1.

[British and American English differences_Cambridge_Studies in the English Lanugage](http://hcot.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Cambridge_English_A_Handbook_of_Word_and_Grammar_Patterns.pdf)

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: With to, it means invite, and without it means make someone do something.

Comment: https://oed.com/oed2/00103269

Comment: @GJC I have answered the question.

Answer (score 3):

"Have someone *to* stay" is an idiomatic way (in British English at least) of saying you received a guest, usually overnight. In this usage, "have" means to *possess* - you *have* a guest in your house. It is comparable with "having someone *to dinner*".

"Have" can also mean that *to cause something to happen or someone to do something*. So to "have someone stay" could mean that you caused them stay - perhaps that you insisted they stay. For example, "she wanted to leave the hospital and go home today, but the doctor had them stay another night just to be sure".

Comment: what is TO here?

Comment: I heartily disagree with this reading. The to is unidiomatic at best.

Comment: @GJC It's a preposition, just as in "have someone to dinner". Inviting someone "to stay".

Comment: The question is not idiomatic. To have mother stay over Christmas. No, to. To have someone to dinner is not the same thing.

Comment: @Lambie Really? Maybe American English is different, I've qualified it by adding this is British English. Having someone *to stay* is as idiomatic as having someone *to dinner*, here.

Comment: I doubt that very much. **have someone to dinner** is completely idiomatic. The other is not even if you plead BrE. have someone to [dinner, lunch, tea] but not to stay.

Comment: @Lambie Then why do people say it? And why can I find tons of examples on Google?

Comment: To have someone to stay sounds like the person is invited. To  have someone stay is not an express invitation but more like make someone do something.

Comment: @lambie This is interesting from an American... https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/we-usually-have-my-mother-to-stay-over-christmas.3816354/

Comment: They mean different things. See the Cambridge paper I quote. I really don't see why I deserve two dvs.

Comment: @lambie It's physically impossible for me to give you two downvotes. I mustn't be the only person who thinks you're wrong. This Lakeland holiday business also thinks you're wrong, check their slogan: http://www.lakesedge.co.uk/

Comment: https://oed.com/oed2/00103269

Comment: I am not wrong: they mean different things. I didn't say you dv'ed me.:)

Comment: I agree that *We had my parents **to** stay over Xmas* strongly implies ***by invitation***, where the same *without* the infinitive marker ***to*** could be used with the same meaning. But the version without ***to*** can *also* carry the implication of "obligation" borne by EITHER the guests OR the hosts (we ***insisted*** on them coming to our house, OR they insisted on coming).